# Select heading element by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I want to select an element by its class, and assign it to a variable, but I want that element to be a heading element. Let me explain: at any given time, there will be exactly 3 elements with this certain class on my page: an `<a>`, a `<p>` and a heading element of unknown type, e.g. `<h1>`, `<h2>`, etc.

Selecting the `<a>` and `<p>` is easy, i.e. `$("a.myclass")`, but I cannot do that with my heading element. I need something like this:

```
var a = $("a.myclass");
var p = $("p.myclass");
var heading = $(some selector to get the heading);
```

Help please!

Also, I am aware that the title of this question isn't a good one. If you so wish, please edit it and reword it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the :header selector - http://api.jquery.com/header-selector/

```
var header = $(":header");
```

It will select all header elements, for example h1, h2, h3...

You can also use this as a filter if you only want header tags with a particular class, for example:

```
var header = $(".myClass").filter(":header");
```

Comment: So, can I write `$(":header.myclass")`?

Comment: see my edit regarding using the selector as a filter, although that will also work

Comment: Per the documentation though, you should see a performance increase using a filter: Because `:header` is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using `:header` cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM `querySelectorAll()` method. To achieve the best performance when using `:header` to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use `.filter(":header")`.

Answer (score 0):

This line will grab any `h1`, `h2`, or `h3` with the `myclass` class:

```
var h = $('h1.myclass, h2.myclass, h3.myclass');
```

If you aren't sure what kind of element whatsoever you can do this to replace all 3 calls:

```
var myclass = $('.myclass');
```

You can also loop through all of them and store it based on the tag name like this:

```
var data = [];

$('.myclass').each(function(){
    data[this.tagName] = this;
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [:header](http://api.jquery.com/header-selector/) selector:

```
var heading = $(":header.myclass");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/XJrwH/1/

Comment: This will work, but you will have improved performance using a standard CSS selector and then filtering the results: `var heading = $(".myclass").filter(":header");`